# WP enqueue style correctly?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Ok, so I am working on my first wordpress theme and looking at other peoples code for help and I came across something which really confused me in the header.php. My question is why do you deregister the style.css before registering it? is this best practice or something.

```
<?php
wp_deregister_style( 'style-css' ); /* Why? */
wp_register_style( 'style-css', get_stylesheet_uri() );
wp_enqueue_style( 'style-css' );
?>
```

So is it best practice to deregister a style before registering and enqueing it?

Comment: sorry if this is a stupid question but im new to wordpress api so I would appreciate an explanation, thanks ;)

Comment: It removes any registered stylesheets with that handle, and adds a new one with the same handle. Why the developer did it is hard to answer, it could be to make sure the right URL was used, or to make sure that a parent themes styles aren't used, or any number of other things

Comment: Is that a child theme?

Comment: nope its avada parent theme

Comment: It doesn't make sense, usually this is done on child themes to unregister parent's CSS and add a new one wich will override the styles.

Comment: I do not understand it either but I just want to know if it is best practice, after all it's from one of the most popular themes out there surely theres some reasoning behind it, the above code is just standard meta data and link profile stuff

Comment: Avada is a great theme, some of the code behind it, not so much, then again the same goes for Wordpress, it's a mess of globals and bad practice code from start to end. If there isn't a very specific reason for deregistering a style or script, you shouldn't do it, and it's not good practice to do so either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Skatox, turns out it is just bad code practice. 
Should be:

```
<?php
wp_register_style( 'style-css', get_stylesheet_uri() );
wp_enqueue_style( 'style-css' );
?>
```

Deregister should only be used for plugins and child themes, not themes themselves!